# SQL Server Case Statement field equals space returns the entire field contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, spaces, case-statement

I'm working with the most bizarrely collated database I've ever seen. I'm running a case statement that sounds simple enough.

Code:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN PMA_DESC = ' '  THEN dbo.CAN_TBL.CAN_DESC 
       ELSE 'NO DESCRIPTION' 
       END AS PMA_DESC  
      , PMA_PART_ONLY
      , PMA_ANAL_FIELD1
      , CAN_DESC
      , PMA_CREATED
      , PMA_UPDATED
FROM dbo.PMA_TBL INNER JOIN
     dbo.CAN_TBL ON dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_ANAL_FIELD1 = dbo.CAN_TBL.CAN_CODE
WHERE        (CAST(dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_CREATED AS DATE) >= DATEADD(dd, - 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) OR
                     CAST(dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_UPDATED AS DATE) >= DATEADD(dd, - 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) AND (dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_DESC IS NOT NULL)
```

That first part of the case statement looking for a space in the field `PMA_DESC` returns the entire column despite only 44 records in the column being populated with nothing but a space. So it's finding any space in the field and giving me the entire contents of the field back as a positive result. I have never seen that since I started working with SQL Server 3 1/2 years ago. Can that be something to do with database collation ? I know this one is set to type that forces case sensitivity (yay).

A selection of results;

```
PMA_DESC        PMA_PART_ONLY   PMA_ANAL_FIELD1     CAN_DESC
NO DESCRIPTION  82240069        82                  GLACIER MTM
NO DESCRIPTION  8228399         82                  GLACIER MTM
NO DESCRIPTION  8235579         82                  GLACIER MTM
```

The first column results already had their own individual part descriptions but because they contained a space between the words, the case statement has transformed it into 'NO DESCRIPTION.' That's not right surely?

How can `[field] = ' '` see any text around spaces as a positive?

Database collation is set to: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: *"Can that be something to do with database collation?"* - probably. Why don't specify what is that collation? Also creating some minimal but complete and reproduceable example would help to resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes, duh, good point. Just added it after finding it in the properties. Thanks.

Comment: The collation has nothing to do with *spaces*. It's the ANSI SQL standard itself, [as explained here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces). Strings are padded with spaces before comparison to ensure both sides have the same length. Use `LEN()` or `DATALEN()`, or even `LIKE ' '`  if you want to match spaces

Comment: What values are stored in the *other* fields? Please provide a reproducible example. If the culprit is the ANSI SQL standard itself, you'll be able to demonstrate this with a very simple table and only a couple of rows

Answer (score 0):

It's me being a dunce and not working out the logic of my case statement properly. This produces the results I need so it was me not working with the empty spaces alongside other values properly.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN PMA_DESC = ' ' AND CAN_DESC IN ('INVOICE ODDBALLS','SLOW MOVING') THEN 'NO DESCRIPTION'
            WHEN PMA_DESC = ' ' AND CAN_DESC NOT IN ('INVOICE ODDBALLS','SLOW MOVING')  THEN CAN_DESC
            ELSE PMA_DESC 
            END AS PMA_DESC , PMA_PART_ONLY, PMA_ANAL_FIELD1, CAN_DESC, PMA_CREATED, PMA_UPDATED
FROM            dbo.PMA_TBL INNER JOIN
                     dbo.CAN_TBL ON dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_ANAL_FIELD1 = dbo.CAN_TBL.CAN_CODE
WHERE        (CAST(dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_CREATED AS DATE) >= DATEADD(dd, - 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) OR
                     CAST(dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_UPDATED AS DATE) >= DATEADD(dd, - 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) AND (dbo.PMA_TBL.PMA_DESC IS NOT NULL)
```

Thanks for taking the time to read though guys, I'll think harder next time!